# Unix regular expression begginers question

Tags: unix, computer-science, automata, qregularexpression

I'm starting the study of regular expressions and I've been wondering how can I build and test the regular expression in UNIX notation for all vowel strings that contain the substring "ai" or "ui".

would it simply be something like: (ai|ui) ? How could I test it?

Comment: So you are searching for a followed by i or u followed by i?

Comment: Imagine all the possible combinations of vowels aeiou:  aeiuo aeuio and etc... I need to select every string that contains the substring ai or ui

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want something like
`'^[aeiou]*?(ai|ui)[aeiou]*$'`. Examples:

```
$ echo aaauiaa | grep -E '^[aeiou]*?(ai|ui)[aeiou]*$'
aaauiaa
$ echo aaaaiaa | grep -E '^[aeiou]*?(ai|ui)[aeiou]*$'
aaaaiaa
```

Comment: When I test this expression on https://www.regexpal.com/ it doesn't select the vowel strings that contain the substring "ai" or "ui. Shouldn't it work there, but anyway it was a bit more clear for me now

Comment: Do not put single quotes, they are only needed by shell. Try `^[aeiou]*?(ai|ui)[aeiou]*$`

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)